How avoid small files using databricks when data is been writing
I am performing two write operations, each in a different notebook. The first operation involves writing approximately 22 million records with 90 columns, and the second involves writing about 10 million records with 99 columns.
Without any configuration, these operations are resulting in over 100 files, each around 40 MiB in size for the 22 million source and around 17 MiB for the 10 million source. To address this, So I tried to use this spark configurations:
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.autoCompact.enabled","auto")
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.targetFileSize","200mb")

But even with that the files size's still the same, I use this documentation
One important detail is that I have a .py file containing several functions, including one that handles writing to storage like:
df.write.mode(mode).format("delta").save(trg_path)

In the notebook, I call this function to perform the write operation. I was uncertain whether the Spark session in the notebook is the same as the one in the .py file. So, I first tried declaring the spark configurations only in the notebook and then in both the notebook and the .py file.
I would like to know if there is a way to avoid those 17Mib or 40Mib files when the data is been writing instead of use OPTIMIZE after the write operation

spark.databricks.delta.targetFileSize setting doesn't guarantee that the file size will be exactly as configured. It serves more as a hint to the optimizer.
Is your data properly partitioned? Having too many partitions can lead to smaller files being created. You may need to adjust the number of partitions using repartition() or coalesce() before writing.

Hi @Kamal, I don't have a clear column or group of columns to use for df.repartition(cols) or partitionBy(). While I could calculate the number of partitions based on the first write operation, I’m interested in knowing if there is a way to set the size of each partition directly.
I considered using autoCompact, but I’m not entirely sure how this configuration works

@Bryc right before writing you can use .repartition(N) where N in your scenario will be basically number of written files
